# Why does my Java repaint() method not work?

Tags: java, graphics2d

Heyo, for my college homework I need to draw some images and race them, but I am stuck even at drawing the images (or in this case, icons). I want to draw ANYTHING (that's why I have the drawLine method, just to test it out) as of right now on one of many JPanels, but my repaint() method does not call my paintComponent method, why?

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.lang.Math; 


public class Races{
   private int numberOfRacers;

   public Races(int numberOfRacers){
      this.numberOfRacers = numberOfRacers;
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Races - Name Surname");

      Icon icon = new ImageIcon("races.jpg");
      frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(numberOfRacers, 1));
      frame.setSize(icon.getIconWidth()*20, (icon.getIconWidth()*2)*numberOfRacers);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      try{
         Thread.sleep(1000);  // Sleeping 1 sec 
         System.out.println("Sleeping one second for the user!");
      }catch(InterruptedException ie){
         System.out.println(ie);
      }


      for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRacers; i++){
         innerRacer racer = new innerRacer();
         frame.add(racer.panel);
         //JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel(icon);
         //iconLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
         //panel.add(iconLabel);
         Thread t = new Thread(racer);
         t.start();

      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){

      if(args.length > 0 && Integer.parseInt(args[0]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(args[0]) < 100){
         Races races = new Races(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));   // From command line number of racers
         System.out.println("Number of racers: " + args[0]);
      }else{
         Races races = new Races(5);      // Default number of racers
         System.out.println("Number of racers: 5");
      }
   }

   public class innerRacer extends JPanel implements Runnable{ 
      JPanel panel;
      Icon icon;
      public innerRacer(){
         panel = new JPanel();
         panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

         icon = new ImageIcon("races.jpg");
      } //end of innerRacer constructor

      @Override
         public void run(){
            repaint();     
            System.out.println("TEST");  
         }
     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawLine(10, 20, 30, 40);
         System.out.println("Why is this one not called?");
         icon.paintIcon(panel, g, 0, 0);
     } 

   } // end of innerRacer class
} //end of Races class
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the `JPanel` that `innerRacer` contains rather than the `JPanel` that `innerRacer` is.

Change:

```
     frame.add(racer.panel);
```

to:

```
     frame.add(racer);
```

Also I see you are adding components to the frame after setting it to visible. When you do this in AWT/Swing they wont get automatically laid out or painted. You will need to follow with the line:

```
  frame.revalidate();
```

Alternatively, the `setVisible` line could be moved down.

As general notes:

- It's a good idea to stick to Java naming conventions - always initial caps for types.
- `JPanel panel;` in `innerRacer` can be deleted.
- Swing components should always be accessed from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`.
- Lots of tutorials suggest overriding `JPanel` without adding any components if you want to paint anything. This appears to be because it is opaque by default. Neither the API docs for `JPanel` nor even the OpenJDK source code mention opaqueness. Indeed, it isn't guaranteed. It's just a hack. Prefer `setOpaque(true)` to make a component opaque.
- Having a class extend another and implement an interface (or implement multiple interfaces (not markers, `Comparable`, etc)) isn't great. Use a lambda method, method reference, inner class or just another outer class as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but sadly, that doesn't quite fix it :(

 `Sleeping one second for the user! TEST TEST TEST TEST Number of racers: 5 TEST `

This is my console output, as you can see - "Why is this one not called?" hasn't been printed out. When I expect it to be printed out 5 times? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mateo I've given it a go. Not having the JPEG, it worked fine when I resized the window to show the contents. Added a bit to my answer about adding components to an already visible window.